# handle DrawerLayout in fragments

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

I am trying to debug an app built with fragments. Since I don't know nearly anything about fragments, I have some problems with them.

1. I want the action button to be transformed in back button when I open a fragment from MainActivity or another fragment.
   I kinda made that work, but when I press back from a fragment and it resumes the other the back button transforms back to home button.
2. I want to know how I can make that home button behave like the back button on Android when it transforms to the back arrow. It does nothing currently.

Here is some code I think it's relevant, I will provide more if you need:

MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_trash_all:
            DataHolder.cart = null;
            isTrashButtonPresent = false;
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            inflateFragment(CartFragment.newInstance(null, null));
            resolveCircularText(DataHolder.getOverallCartQuantity());
            return true;
        case R.id.btnMyMenu:
            if (drawer.getDrawerLockMode(GravityCompat.START)
                  ==DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED) {
                onBackPressed();
            } else {
                drawerToggle();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void drawerToggle() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}

private void setupNavigationDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
          this, drawer, toolbar,
          R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.drawer_icon);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
    setDrawerState(true);
}

public void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
    if (isEnabled) {
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED,
        GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    } else {
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED,
        GravityCompat.START);
        //Drawable backButton = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,
          R.mipmap.ic_back_button);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
    }
}
```

Fragments:

OnCreate:

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setDrawerState(false);
    }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setDrawerState(true);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Can you describe step by step what the user does and how the app should respond at each a step? Screenshots or mockups will help a lot.

Comment: It is a eCommerce app. The MainActivity contains a DrawerLayout with buttons leading to some fragments (My account, wishlist etc.). When the user opens a fragment the DrawerLayout is supposed to get inactive and instead of the DrawerLayout action button it is supposed to appear the back button. That works except that back button does nothing and for example if the user presses back (from the default back button on the phone) and he is backing from a fragment to another fragment the back button dissapears. I will update the question with some screenshots.

Comment: You should edit your question

Comment: You should include descriptions with the screenshots. Do not rely on anyone checking the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Interface` class:

```
public interface DrawerViewInterface {
    void lockDrawer();
    void unlockDrawer();
    void showBackIcon();
    void showHamburgerIcon();
}
```

Now, Implement this `Interface` class in your `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity implements DrawerViewInterface {

    @Override
    public void lockDrawer() {
      drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }

    @Override
    public void unlockDrawer() {
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    }

    @Override
    public void showBackIcon() {
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void showHamburgerIcon() {
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
       mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Now, In your `Fragment`, call whatever you want by:

```
((DrawerViewInterface) getActivity()).showHamburgerIcon();
```

or

```
((DrawerViewInter) getActivity()).showBackIcon();
```

Comment: Thanks, that took care of the button problem. But now I can't seem to make the button work in either burger or back arrow state.